# Text ellipsis is not working

Tags: css

In Firefox, I try to text ellipsis after two line but it is not working. IT is working on chrome but not working in Firefox.

```css
.ellipsis {
    width: 89%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p class="ellipsis">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: `-webkit-line-clamp` only works in Chrome, and has no Firefox alternative - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

Comment: Check [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp) for `webkit-line-clamp`.

Comment: There is no option to use line clamp in Firefox, I mean how to implement ellipsis come after two line